# gcc vs. clang: symbol stripping

Tags: optimization, gcc, llvm, clang, strip

gcc and AMD Open64 opencc both have a `-s` option to "strip symbol table and relocation information". So far I haven't been able to find the same option in Clang/LLVM. Does it exist?

Comment: I think you should use `objcopy` (from binutils) to split off the symbols. This way you will have them handy in case one of your users experiences a crash, but you don't have to include them with the binary you give to users.

Comment: looks like stuff was missed by an occasion. Please fill the PR in LLVM bugzilla. Thanks!

Comment: @Anton Alright, I've filed http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9986 .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a `strip` utility from binutils.

Actually, a llvm-ld has this options http://llvm.org/cmds/llvm-ld.html

> *-strip-all, -s* Strip all debug and symbol information from the executable
>   to make it smaller.
>
> *-strip-debug, -S* Strip all debug information from the executable to
>   make it smaller.

opt have something too:

> *-strip-debug*
>   This option causes opt to strip debug information from the module before applying other 
>   optimizations. It is essentially the same as -strip but it ensures that stripping of debug 
>   information is done first.

Comment: I ended up doing this effectively by passing clang `-Wl,-s`.