# How to strip method names and still have an usable dsym

Tags: qt, linker, clang++, debug-symbols, cracking

I have a QT application with bugsplat integrated therefore I need the DSYM  in case we have a crash, but I also want to make cracking more difficult, some of the first steps are striping the method names.

I'm generating the DSYM with these lines:

```
CONFIG += debug_and_release
CONFIG += force_debug_info
CONFIG += separate_debug_info
```

I managed to strip the symbols with following the commands recommended by this [link](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/4674) :

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Xlinker -unexported_symbol -Xlinker "*"
strip executable
```

unfortunately the DSYM file becomes unusable after the `strip` command (at least that's what Hope Disassembler tells me), if I remove the second command I can still see the method names in the disassembler.

in the strip wiki I can read the following:

> The effect of strip can be achieved directly by the linker. For
>   instance, in GNU Compiler Collection this option is "-s".

I've already tried all sorts of flags combinations

- [Hide function name in GCC compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829699/hide-function-name-in-gcc-compilation)
- [gcc vs. clang: symbol stripping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085491/gcc-vs-clang-symbol-stripping)

But it seems the linker detects when is working with persons that know nothing about these subjects and ignores all my attempts.

Note I'm doing this for mac right now but after this step I need to do it in windows as well.

The compiler being used is: clang++